# How to get my global variables to be available during imports of other modules?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

In python 3 I have a global dictionary, `mydict` that looks like:

```
global mydict #this is line 1
mydict = {'property1':'value',...
```

After this line, I import a module:

```
from my_module import my_mod
```

Putting a breakpoint on the import shows my global as existing as part of the globals.

[image]

Putting a breakpoint on the first line of `my_module` (an import) shows that my variable is not part of the global variables.

I want this global variable to be available in the file that's being imported, at the time it's being imported. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new module

mydict.py

```
mydict = {'property1':'value',...
```

importing.py

```
global mydict #this is line 1
from mydict import mydict
from my_module import my_mod
```

my_module.py

```
from mydict import mydict
```

Other ways would be more difficult, I imagine.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but I didn't want to have to edit the my_module file (or create a whole new file just to hold what is just some overridden configurations)